# iphone Current location not showing

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, mapkit, cllocationmanager

I need help on iphone MapKit! 
I created a simple mapview using interface builder and set the show user location to yes.
However, the "blue dot" is not showing up on my deployed itouch! I need help on it!

Also, anyone can advise how can i get the user current location and plot a route to another location?
Is there no official API for us to use like how apple's map app used ? To draw the route.

Thank you so much!

My code.

**viewDidLoad**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    [locationManager setDelegate:self];
    [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

**locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:**

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

    [mapView setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
    mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;

    MKCoordinateRegion region;

    CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
    location.latitude = newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
    location.longitude = newLocation.coordinate.longitude;

    region.center = location;
    region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.02;
    region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.02;
    [mapView setRegion:region animated:YES]; 
    [mapView setDelegate:self];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For point 2: If you want the show the route with Maps (so your application goes in background) use:

```
NSString* url = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=%f,%f&daddr=%f,%f",fromLocation.latitude, fromLocation.longitude,toLocation.latitude,toLocation.longitude];
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString: url]];
```

If you want to draw the route in your MKMapview i suggest you to look at this https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/MapKit-Route-Directions.

I don't know for the point 1, have you activated location services in Settings?

Answer (score 0):

What did you write in below method ? It is responsible to place blue dot or pin on the user current location.

**Note:** I just copy paste my code so you need to modify it as per your need. In short you just need to return view nil if annotation is user's current location. Then It will have blue dot in center in user's current location automatically.

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)MapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
MKPinAnnotationView *view = nil;

if(annotation !=mapview.userLocation){
    view = (MKPinAnnotationView *) 
    [mapview dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"identifier"]; 
    if(nil == view) { 
        view = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] 
                 initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"identifier"] 
                autorelease];           
    }
    [view setPinColor:MKPinAnnotationColorPurple];
    UIButton *btnViewVenue = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    btnViewVenue.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30);
    view.rightCalloutAccessoryView=btnViewVenue;
    view.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
    view.enabled = YES;
    view.canShowCallout = YES;
    view.multipleTouchEnabled = NO;
    view.animatesDrop = YES;
    }       
return view;
}
```

For your 2nd Point about draw route between two location. So as per my knowledge it is not officially possible to show route between two location in MapKit until you draw lines manually and if you have co-ordinates for all the routes.

Hope this help.